# Calculate minimum and maximum values of each variable in a table in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

Consider the following table:

```
sym A B
X   1 2
Y   4 1
X   6 9
Z   6 3
Z   3 7
Y   1 8
```

I want to find the minimum A value and maximum B value for each of my symbols X, Y & Z and display them in a new table, i.e.

```
sym minA maxB
X   1    9
Y   1    8
Z   3    7
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it;

```
  select minA:min A, maxB:max B by sym from table
```